# emacs dired-mode: How to "exit" and end up in a shell in the current directory?

Tags: emacs, dired

On Mac OS I can use the terminal, write "cd ", and then drag & drop folders from Finder to the terminal. I then obtain something like "cd /Users/..." which allows me to quickly change to the corresponding directory.
If I open an emacs shell with M-x shell and drag & drop a folder to it, emacs changes in dired mode and displays me the content of the folder I dropped. How can I "exit" or "quit" dired-mode and obtain a shell having directory changed to the folder I dropped? That would give me something like above and that would be quite useful.

Comment: If you start shell in emacs (`M-x shell`), it will start in the listed direcotry. You can also run a shell command after pressing `M-!` that will start in the directory.

Comment: thanks, but that's not the point. I have a shell open, started with M-x shell. Of course this is opened in the directory from which I called M-x shell. But now I navigate in dired mode to another directory. The problem is that I don't want to open a file from there, I just want to leave dired-mode and get back to the prompt in the shell, but now the shell should have cd'ed to the directory I navigated to in dired-mode. So putting in pwd should show me the directory I navigated to in dired-mode. If I just hit "q", I end up in the original directory, not in the one I navigated to.

Comment: @choroba M-x shell doesn't work for me.
M-- M-x shell worked instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a function to open a shell instead of dired buffer. This function is useful in many other cases, not only in a case of DnD

```
(require 'dired)
(define-key dired-mode-map "c" 'shell-instead-dired)

(defun shell-instead-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dired-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (shell (concat default-directory "-shell"))
    (kill-buffer dired-buffer) ;; remove this line if you don't want to kill the dired buffer
    (delete-other-windows)))
```

**EDIT** In this case you need to DnD a directory in Emacs and press 'c' to call a shell in this directory.

Otherwise you may install a [smart-dnd](http://braeburn.aquamacs.org/code/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/smart-dnd.el) package and configure it to open a shell. I provides also other useful stuff like creating `<img ...>` tags in html mode if you drop a jpg or `#include<...>` in c-mode if you drop a header.

Comment: okay, I see, not an easy task. So far I just use
1) M-x dired
2) navigate with "a" to the folder you like
3) C-u M-x shell => this shell opens in the folder you navigated to under 2)

Comment: Well, it's all about speed, right. You DnD a directory into Emacs which shows it in a dired mode. Using my solution you type a single key 'c' which opens a shell with the unique name and closes the dired buffer

Comment: I obtain: Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map

Comment: You need to add  (require 'dired)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :-) So the solution is 1) C-x d 2) navigate with "a" 3) c

Comment: When you work with OS navigator (Explorer for Windows, .. for Mac) you need only to DnD a directory in Emacs and press 'c'. Otherwise you can navigate from dired in Emacs and press 'c' once you are in directory you need.

Comment: Is there a way to do inverse action i.e.:
1. Inside emacs I have opened terminal
2. I want to jump with dired to the current directory opened in terminal (terminal is open INSIDE emacs)
?

Comment: @micholeodon I tried in my emacs C-x C-f and it suggests the current directory opened in terminal. I don't think I modified anything in emacs to have this behaviour

Comment: @OlegPavliv I tried this and I have no suggestions. I use some packages that may overlap this behaviour:  multi-term,  helm

Comment: M-- M-x eshell   does it for me. 
It's equivalent to   C-u M-x eshell   but i consider it a small improvement.